# IOS XCODE crash with error : Dispatch queue: com.apple.root.default-qos

Tags: iphone, xcode, crash

I installed a Mac image in VMWare and installed XCode 6.1. When I run a project the IDE encounters a bad access. Has anyone encountered this issue and is there any resolution for this issue?

I am getting error "Dispatch queue: com.apple.root.default-qos

```
Exception Type:        EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes:       KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000000000010"
```

Below is full crash report:

```
Process:               Xcode [299]
Path:                  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode
Identifier:            com.apple.dt.Xcode
Version:               6.3.1 (7703)
Build Info:            IDEFrameworks-7703000000000000~4
App Item ID:           497799835
App External ID:       812230896
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        ??? [1]
Responsible:           Xcode [299]
User ID:               501

Date/Time:             2015-04-26 19:36:47.627 -0700
OS Version:           Mac OS X 10.10 (14A238x)
Report Version:        11
Anonymous UUID:        F379DDE0-7D57-C054-0C16-360F7F63CAE3


Time Awake Since Boot: 230 seconds

Crashed Thread:        11  Dispatch queue: com.apple.root.default-qos

Exception Type:        EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes:       KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000000000010

VM Regions Near 0x10: -->
__TEXT                 0000000109edf000-0000000109ee0000 [    4K] r-x/rwx SM=COW  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode
Application Specific Information:
ProductBuildVersion: 6D1002

Thread 0:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8c5a35ae mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8c5a275f mach_msg + 55
2   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8ad78d64    __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 212
3   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8ad78255 __CFRunLoopRun + 1381
4   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8ad77aa8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 296
5   com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff869e3b3f RunCurrentEventLoopInMode   + 235
6   com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff869e38b2   ReceiveNextEventCommon + 431
7   com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff869e36f3 _BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInModeWithFilter + 71
8   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff89453825 _DPSNextEvent + 1000
9   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff89452ff9 -[NSApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 139
10  com.apple.dt.DVTKit             0x000000010a633dda -[DVTApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 237
11  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff89446fe3 -[NSApplication run] + 594
12  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff89432a9e NSApplicationMain +        1778
libdyld.dylib                   0x00007fff8cc055c9 start + 1
```

Thanks

Comment: The problem statement was within the code snippet. Restructured the format to highlight the problem statement and updated formatting.

Comment: Normally you would send a bug report to Apple. However, it seems that you installed Xcode not on a Mac, but using VMWare, which means you don't have a valid license to run the operating system and any software on it, so I doubt they will help you.

Comment: Thanks gnasher729.  I got the point. Hopefully someone who attempted in VMWare and hit this issue may have the solution and can help m.

Comment: finally i found a solution. There are some missing patches and updates to OS and Xcode. once i install all the patches, this issue is resolved

Comment: @narsibattula I have same crash. would you please help me to find solution? What are missing patches and updates to OS and Xcode? How can I install it? i am using OS 10.10.5 and Xcode 7.2 .

Answer (score 0):

Solution: to modify the UI code put back to the main thread

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
// addSubview,insertSubview
});
```